# How to set WP7 ItemsPanel in code behind?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox created in code behind and I need to set the ItemsPanelTemplate to WrapPanel programmatically. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in pure code. THe VisualTree property isn't accessible.
(The way you would do this in WPF is to use the `FrameworkElementFactory` but this is not available in Silverlight.)

The only way to do this appears to be through creating the XAML as a string and then using [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190359%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).